# PHP/MySQL for Lunar calendar

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Yii2 and MySQL do make a lunar calendar app.
I've got 2 fields in table: normal_date and lunar_date (of type DATE). Here the problem occurs:
With normal calendar, date 1950-04-16 should be date 1950-02-30 in lunar calendar.
Neither PHP DateTime class or MySQL DATE type accept that.
What i want to ask is what type should i use to store the lunar_date data and what PHP library should i use to work with this kind of data.

My application has to convert between normal_date and lunar_date very usual, and my database will be very large because i will store data from 1950 to 2050.

Comment: Use yyyy-mm-dd format.  Much easier to read, and plays well with most (all?) systems.

Comment: Sorry, it's my bad. The correct data i'm using in MySQL is Y-m-d. But the main point is 1950-02-30 is lunar date, in normal date it doesn't exist. MySQL and DateTime doesn't allows that. For PHP example: $date = new DateTime('1950-02-30');
        echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // 02-03-1950.

Comment: Well, for MySQL, you can store it as as varchar instead of a date.  You won't be able to do MySQL operations such as `+ INTERVAL 1 WEEK` though.  I'm not really sure what your use-case is here, so I'm not sure if it's realistic for you to do the same in PHP.  All depends on what your application is actually doing.  If you're literally just taking a "normal" date and outputting a "lunar date", then you should be fine handling the dates as strings in PHP instead of something like DateTime.  If you're trying to perform operations/calculations though, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @patrickQ Yes, thanks for your comment. I think i would use varchar type for that. Still need advice for PHP solution

Comment: Like I said, it all depends on what you're actually doing with the dates.

Comment: what lunar calendar are you referring to?

Comment: It's Chinese calendar @Walter Tross

Comment: I don't read Chinese, but you might have a look at [THIS](https://github.com/overtrue/chinese-calendar)

Comment: Thank you very much Patrick. I'm looking at it right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a Gregorian calendar date to store Chinese lunar calendar dates, because they obey different rules, as your attempt to store `1950-02-30` clearly shows. Also operations like adding a number of days to a date, which are possible both in MySQL and in PHP, would be incompatible.

So you mainly have two choices:

- handle and store lunar dates as strings, like `"1950-02-30"`, or
- handle and store lunar dates as triples of integers, like a `SMALLINT` and two `TINYINT`s in MySQL and a `class` with 3 numeric properties in PHP (for cleanliness, but passing around 3 variables is possible too).

Let me mention that you might find it useful to convert dates into the most common intermediate representation for calendar conversions, which is the [Julian Day Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day). In PHP you have [`gregoriantojd`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gregoriantojd.php) and [`jdtogregorian`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdtogregorian.php), in MySQL you can use `TO_DAYS(gregorian_date) + 1721060` and `FROM_DAYS(julian_day_number - 1721060)`. Unfortunately nothing the like exists for the Chinese calendar (although it does for the Hebrew calendar in PHP), so that's where your fine art kicks in.

Comment: Thanks Walter Tross, first choice solved the problems.